# Concerning workflow of a second commit without a previous push

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to `git` and I am trying to understand the workflow.
Let's say that I did a `git commit` but did not `push` the file to the repository.
This means a local commit, right?
Now I realize that I need some more changes to do in this same file otherwise my previous commit is incomplete/incorrect.
I start modifying the file and make the changes. Now the `git log` will show that the last commit was mine (the one I mentioned previously that I submitted) and the `git status` will show that there are untracked changes in the same file.
So now, what is the correct procedure?
Do I do `git add` the new changes, and then do `git commit` and finally `git push`?
In the end in the repository how many versions are stored. The first incomplete and the second one? That contains the extra needed changes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a distributed system, which means that you have all the commits local. You are correct when you say you need to git add the file, and then commit again. You can then decide if you want to push or not.

Note that when you push, git pushes history, not files individually. History in this context means the commits with associated files.

You might want to read a [book](http://git-scm.com/documentation) about git which tells you more about how you work with git. That'll give you some basic concepts so you understand better what is happening when you do what.

Comment: So when I push I will push both the commits.The incomplete and the complete version.And the latest version would be the last commit right? So is there a way to not push the first version of the file? Wouldn't it be better to have only the last commit?

Comment: If you want to modify the first commit, before you have pushed, instead of doing just `git commit`, use `git commit --amend`. This will update the previous commit, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would want to `git add` in your current changes, `git commit`, and `git push`.

`git log` will only show you previous commits that you've made, where as `git status` will show you current changes that have not been committed.

After you commit your changes, you will still only have one version on your machine, however, you will have the incomplete first commit, and the second commit stored in your git branch. Then when you do a `git status`, you will be able to see both your first and second commit.